# Azure Search ranking cities by country (second search field)

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

For testing I've created a index with cities from the whole world. Each city has a name, a geolocation, a country code,....

With the following search

```
https://mySearchUrl.search.windows.net/indexes/cities/docs?search=York&api-version=2015-02-28
```

Would return **York** and **New York** besides other results.

Now i would like to define that results in the US (in this example assumed as user culture) should get higher rankings and should be more likely included then the uk results.

How can I do this?

So I should get New York more likely then just York. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

you can accomplish this using scoring profiles feature of Azure Search, in particular tag boosting scoring function. For an example, see http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2015/02/05/personalizing-search-results-announcing-tag-boosting-in-azure-search/. (BTW, although that link uses REST API, we have full support for scoring profiles in .NET SDK). 
HTH,
Eugene